# Room Database DAO Query to SUM() column with int values and return it... Using MVM Model

Tags: java, sqlite, android-room

I am building an app with android room database. everything works fine. I can insert, update and delete from database. I am trying to add up tthe columns and return their value in an activity(UI).

I tried to add a query in the DAO interface to sum the column and then added the `AsyncTask` in the repository but I am so confused wether I should make a new viewmodel and adapter for the totals activity

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
public class notetable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String date;

    private int pay;

    private int miles;

    private int orders;

    private int expenses;

    public notetable(String date, int miles, int pay, int orders, int expenses) {

        this.date = date;
        this.pay = pay;
        this.miles = miles;
        this.orders = orders;
        this.expenses = expenses;
    }
}
```

DAO Interface:

```
@Dao
public interface notedao {

    @Insert
    void insert(notetable note);

    @Update
    void update(notetable note);

    @Delete
    void delete(notetable note);

    @Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
    void deleteAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table ORDER BY date DESC")
    LiveData<List<notetable>> getAllNotes();

     @Query("SELECT SUM(pay) as totalpay FROM note_table") // this is where 
     I am stuck
int getPayTotal();

}
```

The activity in which I am trying to show the totals

```
public class DashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView totaldatecount, totalmiles, totalpay, totalorders, 
totalexpenses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash);
        totaldatecount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_totaldays);
        totalmiles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_totalmiles);
        totalpay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_totalmoney);
        totalorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_totalorder);
        totalexpenses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_totalexpense);

    }
}
```

Repository :

```
  private static class GetPayTotatlAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, 
     Void>{

    private notedao noteDao;

    private GetPayTotatlAsyncTask(notedao noteDao) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        noteDao.getPayTotal();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I did not follow exactly why are you stuck, would you mind elaborate a little more?

Comment: I am sorry, I am newbie but trying hard. I have this note_table in a room database. I am using MVM model to populate a recycle view with cardviews from user inputs. Everything works fine. User can insert, update, or delete a note. I am trying to use the SUM() function in the DAO to calculate a column sum. I used this @Query("SELECT SUM(pay) as totalpay FROM note_table") int getPayTotal(); and I used the AsyncTask in the repository with the getPayTotal() but I don't what to do next

Comment: Do you want to update your screen with sum?

Comment: Hey Valgaal. yes. I just want to be able to sum those columns(miles,pay...) and display it in my dash activity.

Comment: There is no need to make seperate ViewModel/Activity. Could you please explain what exactly is not working in your code?

Comment: You need to return that value! see your method doInBackground, it should return the noteDao.getPayTotal(); not null.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return the value not "null".

> private static class GetPayTotatlAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,
> Void,
> Void> {
>
> ```
>     private notedao noteDao;
>
>     private GetPayTotatlAsyncTask(notedao noteDao) {
>         this.noteDao = noteDao;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
>         int total = noteDao.getPayTotal();
>         return total;
>     }
> }
> ```

In the Activity class :

> int result = new GetPayTotatlAsyncTask.execute().get();
> totalpay.setText(result);